# swift: how to call a function in Observableobject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just picked up swift programming and I am trying to call a function when a view is loaded. For example I want to call getValue() when the searchResult view is display so that getValue can populate the array i need in the view.

```
class SearchResultViewModel: ObservableObject {
      
    var searchResults:[Any] = [] // ->Creates an instance of the struct object
    var aisleArry: [Int] = []
     init() {
        self.getValue()
      }
    
    func getValue(){
        
        print("We have activated searchModel")
        for (productId , productVal) in Global.productDict {
            let aisle = productVal.aisleNo
            let name  =  productVal.name
            let aislezone = productVal.location_zone
            let aislesect = productVal.location_section
            let price = productVal.productPrice

            if aisleArry.contains(aisle){
                print("already in aisle array")
                
            } else {
                aisleArry.append(aisle)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
 }
```

here is the searchResult view that uses the model above

```
struct SearchResultView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: SearchResultViewModel
   
    
        var body: some View {
 
            VStack {
                VStack{
                  
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(0 ..< model.aisleArry.count){aisleNum in
                            Text(String(self.model.aisleArry[aisleNum])).bold()
                            
                        }
 
                    }
                    
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

after playing around with many methods, the last i tried was self.getValue which does not work. How can I call functions in the view model when the view is loaded?

The getValue function is not being called when the searchResultView is called. How do I call the getValue function when searchResultView is displayed?

Comment: Have you also "just picked up" using Stack Overflow. Please format your code properly. Those javascript run code snippet buttons are completely inappropriate. And try to get indentation of curly braces right.

Comment: @matt thank you. I've edited it.

Comment: You are calling it from the `init` method so the question is how do you initialise SearchResultViewModel and pass it to SearchResultView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it on appear

```
struct SearchResultView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: SearchResultViewModel
    
        var body: some View {
 
            VStack {
                VStack{
                  
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(0 ..< model.aisleArry.count){aisleNum in
                            Text(String(self.model.aisleArry[aisleNum])).bold()
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .onAppear { self.model.getValue() }  // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

and make model really observable

```
 class SearchResultViewModel: ObservableObject {
      
    @Published var searchResults:[Any] = []
    @Published var aisleArry: [Int] = []
    
    func getValue(){
        
        print("We have activated searchModel")

        // ... other code
}
```